# justify multilingual text without the text-align justify property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a multilingual website (currently only in french and english), and there are some places where there is multi line content (titles) a bit like this one :

```css
.banner-heading{
    font-size: 37.2px;
}

.banner-second-heading{
    font-size: 46px;
}

.banner-third-heading{
    font-size: 78px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flexCenter flexColumn col-xs-12 col-md-6 title-fr">     
    <h1 class="banner-heading">Une solution digitale</h1>   
    <h1 class="banner-second-heading">pour le bien-être</h1>
    <h1 class="banner-third-heading">au travail</h1>
</div>
```

And the designer wants it to be done without the justify property, because it would deform the font they've chosen.

My problem is I currently do exactly the same for english as well (with different values to keep the text well aligned at beginning and end of lines), but it is already annoying to maintain in the current states, and should we decide to add other languages, it would become almost impossible to have one css PER language, especially with different `font-size` per line and per language.

So my question is : how do I achieve the same result, in different languages, without using the justify property, given it would deform the chosen font, and without having to play with the `font-size`property in the different languages.

Thank you very much for your help, and sorry if this question was already answered, I searched it and didn't find any answer.

Comment: I don't use it, instead I have to change the ```font-size``` to align it myself without this property (because of graphical issues) @uom-pgregorio

Comment: Designers should provide you with the font sizes and you can apply them for both languages. Their design mock should already have the titles lined up I assume. They should of done it for both languages

Comment: That's why I'm asking a question. (Especially given that in the current state, it means that whenever the text changes, the css has to follow.)
But I don't see how letter-spacing would be any better (and designer don't like the way justify render)... @Pete

Comment: @Huangism Well I don't think they have (at least not for english), and they simply say that the lines have to be aligned well (without the ```text-align: justify``` property), plus it doesn't seem _right_ to me to link so strongly the css and the textual content.

Comment: @JonathanSimonney it isn't good to link the text so closely with the css, but sometimes designers can be very stubborn and want things perfect at all times. If your site is responsive then I would simply deny the request because who knows how many break points you will have to add for text to line up and that is just not practical. If this is the only instance then I would let them know this is a one off and it is not practical/good practice to have css and text to couple so closely but for this time I will do it. Ask them to provide a mock with desired look, it's their job

Comment: At the end of the day you have to educate them on what's practical and what is not. Explain to them how this is not good for maintenance and creates a lot of unnecessary overhead. If they insist you can always go to your supervisor. You definitely shouldn't be the one trying to figure out the perfect font size

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the time. I just wanted to be sure there was no way around that I didn't think of, and you confirmed there wasn't. If anyone wants to propose an answer stating this (or finding a workaround I didn't think of), I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: As you have now added js tag - here is a jquery solution for you (I couldn't be bothered to convert to native js which is why it isn't posted as an answer): https://jsfiddle.net/c22fctb3/16

Comment: Well the platform already uses jquery, so I added it as a tag as well. You may therefore add it as an answer @Pete. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below uses jQuery to calculate the width of the largest line and then use that width to create a ratio and calculate a new font size

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

$wrapper.each(function() {
  var $spans = $(this).find('.equalise'),
    max = 0,
    fontsize = 0;

  $spans.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      width = $this.outerWidth();

    if (max < width) {
      $spans.removeClass('max');
      $this.addClass('max');
      max = width;
      fontsize = parseInt($this.css('font-size'));
    }
  });

  $spans.not('.max').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      ratio = max / $this.outerWidth();
    $this.css('font-size', fontsize * ratio)
  });
});
```

```css
.equalise {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="equalise">line 1 text</span><br>
  <span class="equalise">big font</span><br>
  <span class="equalise">a lot more text for to show how this works</span><br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="equalise">another example</span><br>
  <span class="equalise">a line with some text</span><br>
  <span class="equalise">short stuff</span><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I under stand your problem, you need to change the size of the font/text to fit the container.

Here is a solution that uses svg and a little JavaScript to achieve that.

First we must use svg to write out the text

```
<svg  width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
  <text class="scalableText" x="0" y="15">Une solution digitale</text>  
</svg>
```

then we have to measure the text and change to viewport to fit the text.

```
var textElements = document.getElementsByClassName('scalableText');
for(var i = 0;i < textElements.length; i++)
{
    var textLength = textElements[i].getComputedTextLength();
    textElements[i].parentElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + textLength + " 20"); 
}
```

```js
var textElements = document.getElementsByClassName('scalableText');
for(var i = 0;i < textElements.length; i++) {
  var textLength = textElements[i].getComputedTextLength();
  textElements[i].parentElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + textLength + " 20"); 
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
  <text class="scalableText" x="0" y="15">Une solution digitale</text>  
</svg>
  
<svg width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
  <text class="scalableText" x="0" y="15">pour le bien-être</text>  
</svg>
  
<svg width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
  <text class="scalableText" x="0" y="15">au travail</text>  
</svg>
```

[Example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dowuzipocu/2/edit)

Comment: While this may achieve what was requested, and this is a clever approach for sure, its important to keep in mind that it would be a poor decision to use this as a widespread solution.

Comment: Could you develop please @Trevor? Is this solution bad because the problem in itself (justifying text only by using font-size) is bad, or is it bad because this solution uses svg (which shouldn't be used to write text I suppose), or some other reason I am not aware of. Thank you very much.

Comment: Its a poor solution for widespread use because SVG is meant as a mechanism for rendering graphics, not as a tool to build an entire website. Websites are more than graphics. They include lots of useful content as text and this information should be available in the markup as text for a variety of reasons, ranging from screen reader support for accessibility and web crawler support for proper analysis by search engines. So if the website is a graphical portfolio or something similiar, then the SVG solution might be great, but if this is a regular website then use it minimally (if at all).

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can think of svg as images. but svg text has some advantages over imags for example it can be indexed because the text is in the markup, and it is selectable in the browser and they scale. Like with image you can provide aria attributes to help screen readers and search crawlers.

You would never use this technique to render the main content of a website, like you would not use an image for the main content. But it could be use full to render heading, banners and other cosmetic content and I would not hesitate to use it on a production website as such.